# How do I center a MaxiMenu CK menu in Joomla?

Tags: css, menu, joomla2.5

I am using the MaxiMenu CK menu system for my client's Joomla 2.5.11 website and for some
reason the top navigation (horizontal) won't center.

Please help!

Here is the site: http://scientific-practices.com

I've added `text-align:center` to the containing `div` and the `ul`, to no avail. The list 
items aren't floated, they are `inline-block`, so that shouldn't impede my efforts.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in line 24 of moo_maximenuhck.css:

```
div.maximenuckh ul.maximenuck li.maximenuck{float: left;
```

All you need to do is add float:none to line 233 in template.css.

```
#nav ul.menu li {
display: inline-block;
background: transparent;
margin-left: 16px;
position: relative;
float: none;
}
```